# I want to save the downloaUrl of image in the database using angularfire2

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I was able to fetch the url of the item in storage but i am not able to save them to the database. item.downloadUrl cannot receive the this.imageUrl. Is there any other way to save the downloadUrl of an item to database?

```
 addItem(item){
      // @TODO - Storage ref 
     let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();


     for(let selectedFile of [(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('image')).files[0]]){

       let path=`/${this.folder}/${selectedFile.name}`;
       let iRef= storageRef.child(path);
       iRef.put(selectedFile).then((snapshot)=>{
         item.image=selectedFile.name;
         item.path=path;

         storageRef.child(item.path).getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
           //Setting Image Url below
         this.imageUrl =url;
         item.downloadUrl=this.imageUrl; 
         console.log(this.imageUrl);
       });

         return this.items.push(item);

       }).catch((error)=>{
         console.log(error);
       });
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pushing the item to the database, when the download URL hasn't been retrieved yet. To fix this, move the call to `databaseRef.push()` into the then:

```
let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

for(let selectedFile of [(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('image')).files[0]]){

   let path=`/${this.folder}/${selectedFile.name}`;
   let iRef= storageRef.child(path);
   iRef.put(selectedFile).then((snapshot)=>{
      item.image=selectedFile.name;
      item.path=path;

      return storageRef.child(item.path).getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
         //Setting Image Url below
         this.imageUrl =url;
         item.downloadUrl=this.imageUrl; 
         console.log(this.imageUrl);
         return this.items.push(item);
      });
   }).catch((error)=>{
     console.log(error);
   });
}
```

But you can simplify the code considerably by using the download URL directly from the snapshot that you get in the completion callback from `storageRef.put()`:

```
for(let selectedFile of [(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('image')).files[0]]){
   let path=`/${this.folder}/${selectedFile.name}`;
   let iRef= storageRef.child(path);
   iRef.put(selectedFile).then((snapshot)=>{
      item.image=selectedFile.name;
      item.path=path;
      var url = snapshot.downloadURL;

      this.imageUrl =url;
      item.downloadUrl=this.imageUrl; 
      return this.items.push(item);
   });
}
```